# What would be a good architecture and which tools should I use for downloading and processing multiple files once per month in a cloud like AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, bigdata, cloud, airflow

Hey Stackflow Community,
I'm looking for a good architecture and tools to meet the following requirements:

At a specific day every month do automatically:

- Fetch a list of urls to download from from sources in the internet(At the moment a python script which saves a csv of urls to download)
- download and save pdf-files as fast as possible (in parallel?) and handle http errors like to many requests 429(retry after x seconds?) and 404 errors(log them)
- run a script in python which will go through every pdf-file, extracts some informations from the text and stores them in a dataframe which will be exported as csv. How to parallelize it? Map/Reduce in cluster or simply one big machine with many cpu cores?

I want to do set this up on a cloud service like AWS.

One solution I have in my mind is setting up an Airflow Container which starts all these tasks in order.
In this solution I have the disadvantage that I have to pay for this container the whole month but I only need it one time a month. I don't want to manually startup and shutdown the instance every time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

Comment: aws lambda with step function is my choice.

Comment: It's also my choice! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this question by myself because I found a really good solution.

I used AWS serverless and PaaS tools.

Workflow/architecture is as follows:

1. A CloudWatch event triggers a specified lambda function at the first weekday of every month
2. The called lambda function extracts the metadata from the AWS CloudWatch call(i.e. the actual time) and calls a script to download a csv and save it to the S3 storage service. Then another script will be called with the path of the csv file as a parameter. An advantage of using lambda is that you get another IP address for every request so you won't run in rate limits and will not be blocked.
3. The script starts some AWS Step Functions with a Map function. The reason for using AWS Step Functions is to control the maximal requests at once. If I would call a lambda function on every file than 10000 download requests will hit the server at the same time which will break most servers. I had to split my requests into multiple Step Functions because of the maximum number of 25,000 events per StepFunction instance.
4. The downloaded files will be added to a queue in AWS SQS that calls a lambda function on every file
5. A lambda function gets the addresses of the files from the SQS and extracts the data of each file in json files that will be stored in S3. If the extraction fails the file will be added to a SQS queue that contains paths of failed files. Ready for manual processing and bug fixing
6. A schema from the stored json files will be created with the help of AWS Glue
7. The data in the schema can be queried and extracted in AWS Athena